# Create or insert an xml into a CDATA

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, cdata

I have been testing something but I can not make it work, here is the problem:

I have an xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<history>
    <name>
        <age/>
    </name>
</history>
```

I would like to insert a CDATA in that XML and the content of the CDATA is part of the xml as well, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<history>
    <![CDATA[
    <name>
        <age/>
    </name>
    ]]>
</history>
```

I am using DOMDocument to create the xml:

```
        header('Content-Type: text/xml');
        $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
        $base = $xml->appendChild($xml->createElement('history'));

        $name = $base->appendChild($xml->createElement('name'));
        $age = $name->appendChild($xml->createElement('age'));
        $test = $xml->saveXML();

        $xml->getElementsByTagName('history')->item(0)->appendChild($xml->createCDATASection($test));

        $xml->formatOutput = true;
        echo $xml->saveXML();
```

it generates this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<history>
    <name>
    <age/>
    </name>
    <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><history><name><age/></name></history>]]>
</history>
```

The problems I am facing at the moments are:

1. The way I look at how CDATA works, it looks like I need to complete all the 'inner xml' before I can cut that 'inner xml' and then create the cdata section and paste it into the cdata section
2. I am using a temporary solution which is str_replace, but I would like to utilize the domdocument createCData function as much as possible.

Comment: including XML in CDATA doesn't look good to me. What's the purpose?

Comment: @michi somehow our partner's API requires us to include it, without it they give System Error.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. The CDATA sections are text for outer document, the xml fragment inside a CDATA is its own document or fragment.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
$xml->appendChild($historyNode = $xml->createElement('history'));

$innerXml = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
$innerXml->appendChild($nameNode = $innerXml->createElement('name'));
$nameNode->appendChild($ageNode = $innerXml->createElement('age'));

$fragment = $innerXml->saveXml($innerXml->documentElement);

$historyNode->appendChild($xml->createCDATASection($fragment));

$xml->formatOutput = true;
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<history><![CDATA[<name><age/></name>]]></history>
```

This will only work if the fragment has a single root node (is a valid xml document). If it has several nodes on the top level you will need a dummy node. I added 'address' to the next example to show the difference:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
$xml->appendChild($historyNode = $xml->createElement('history'));

$innerXml = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
$innerXml->appendChild($fragmentNode = $innerXml->createElement('fragment'));
$fragmentNode->appendChild($nameNode = $innerXml->createElement('name'));
$nameNode->appendChild($ageNode = $innerXml->createElement('age'));
$fragmentNode->appendChild($addressNode = $innerXml->createElement('address'));

$fragment = '';
foreach ($fragmentNode->childNodes as $childNode) {
  $fragment .= $innerXml->saveXml($childNode);
}

$historyNode->appendChild($xml->createCDATASection($fragment));

$xml->formatOutput = true;
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<history><![CDATA[<name><age/></name><address/>]]></history>
```